# Excel file Download Not working in node.js using exceljs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

Hi i am new to MEAN Stack.

I want to download the excel file when i click the export button.

I am using this reference link to download the excel file :https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs

> Html Page

```
<button ng-click="exportData()" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-create">Export</button>
```

> my controller

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable", "angularUtils.directives.dirPagination", "ngNotify", "ngCookies", "ngRoute"]);
        app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
        }]);

app.controller('ManageMaterialFlowController', ['$http', '$scope', '$window', '$filter', '$notify', '$cookieStore',  'StoreService',
 function ($http, $scope, $window, $filter, $notify, $cookieStore, StoreService, $routeProvider) {



     //download excel file button click

     $scope.exportData = function () {

         router.get('/download', function (req, res) {

             try {
                 var Excel = require('exceljs');
                 var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
                 var options = {
                     filename: './Excel.xlsx',
                     useStyles: true,
                     useSharedStrings: true
                 };
                 var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
                 var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('My Sheet');

                 worksheet.columns = [
                     { header: 'Id', key: 'id', width: 10 },
                     { header: 'Name', key: 'name', width: 32 },
                     { header: 'D.O.B.', key: 'DOB', width: 10 }
                 ];
                 worksheet.addRow({ id: 1, name: 'John Doe', dob: new Date(1970, 1, 1) });
                 worksheet.addRow({ id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe', dob: new Date(1965, 1, 7) });

                 var tempFilePath = tempfile('.xlsx');
                 workbook.xlsx.writeFile(tempFilePath).then(function () {
                     console.log('file is written');
                     res.sendFile(tempFilePath, function (err) {
                         console.log('---------- error downloading file: ' + err);
                     });
                 });
             } catch (err) {
                 console.log('OOOOOOO this is the error: ' + err);
             }

         });

     };
}
```

I don't know how to do this. is this is correct to way to download the excel file by clicking the button.

when I click the button i getting router is not defined error.  Can any one solve my issue.

Comment: Hi, You have added your server code in client side(AngularJS), you can refer [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) for your Node.js (here you can set url's using express.Router()) development and for your client side file download refer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/esy4kLm2/5/)

Comment: For your server code you can use the same code that you have right now and store in a folder, then for download you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express)

Comment: Hi Kanagu, in your fiddle link not display anything.( Express.js ) nothing is there.  Before i have tried like this can you refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369082/excel-download-is-not-working-in-mean-stack-app?noredirect=1#comment75820326_44369082

Comment: what is the definition of `exportData()` function?

Comment: Hi rupali, exportData() is ng-click function.if i click the button it will download the excel file

Comment: @Vinoth I think you are confused between the node.js code and angular code. The controller is a .js file. You have directly copied the code for excel without understanding what it does. The router is a variable of express router. var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

Comment: Hi code in progress, i have created my file i don't know how to download the file can you give me some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I referred this link to wirte the data to excel sheet.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs

for downloading excel sheet I used this code to download the excel sheet.

```
 var fileName = "Task" + '_Template.xlsx';
    var tempFilePath = __dirname + "\\public\\template\\" + fileName;
    workbook.xlsx.writeFile(tempFilePath).then(function () {
        res.send(fileName);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use

```
workbook.xlsx.writeFile()
```

writeFile() method is for saving file to hard disk.

Instead, use write() method. This method writes file to a stream.

res object is a Writable stream. So you can use like this.

```
workbook.xlsx.write(res)
```

and you don't need to call

```
res.sendFile(tempFilePath)
```

Because you already piplined excel file to res object. So code is like this

```
workbook.xlsx.write(res).then(function () {
    res.status(200).end();
});
```

Finally, You should add https headers on res object.

```
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=YOUR_FILENAME.xlsx");
```

Content-Type notify Web Browser that what data type is.

Content-Disposition notify Web Browser that this data will be saved to hard disk.

Final code is here.

```
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Rep1ort.xlsx");

workbook.xlsx.write(res).then(function () {
    res.status(200).end();
});
```

Comment: when you get repsonse on reactjs how to download file

Comment: axios.get(`myRoute`, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
      .then(response => {
        const blob = new Blob([response.data], {
          type:
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        });

        FileDownload(blob, `file.xlsx`); // npm " js-file-download" responsible for downloading the file for the user
      }); on react js I get data as above when file downloaded as corrupt